# How to let div overlap a "position: fixed" container and scroll vertically with fixed containers content

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have a fixed container in a single page application and I want that one div inside this container overlaps the fixed container's boundaries **and also** vertically scroll with the contents of the fixed container. However, I'm getting the one or the other to work, but not both of them. I'm wondering if there is a CSS only solution?

There is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuebner81/kxpeLn2d/) that demonstrates the issue.

### The goal

[Example imaged removed due to missing reputation. It can be found [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApjuqMm7OcpLp5QYqB69oGl020S0xA).]

The functional goal is to have a clickable marker next to an input control in a fixed positioned sidebar, where the customer can edit several properties of a business item. The marker should overlap the container's boundaries to stand out more. Based on this, there are at least five requirements I want to achieve:

- The topmost container needs to have position: fixed, as the SPA in background can be scrolled in both directions
- The content of the topmost, fixed container should scroll vertically if required but must not scroll horizontally
- A box should be placed next to a target in the content
- This box should overlap the topmost container's boundaries
- This box should scroll vertically when the topmost container's content is scrolled (and therefore the box's target)

The basic structure is fixed container > content(s) > overlapping div. I'm aware of the fact that a combination of overflow and relative positioning will stop overlapping of an absolute positioned child. Therefore I've tried several variations of CSS rules and HTML markup - but in the end either the box was overlapping or does scroll with it's target. Your ideas on how to solve this without code behind are greatly appreciated.

### The code

This is the (simplified) HTML markup:

```
<div class="sidebar-container">
  <div class="sidebar-content-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      <div class="sidebar-content-main">
        <!-- more content -->
        <div class="overlap-container">
          <div class="overlap-wrapper">
            <div class="overlap-relative-container">
              <div class="overlap-box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlap-caption">Some text, the box should appear left to this element.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- more content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The topmost container is fixed:

```
.sidebar-container {
  position: fixed;
  // [ ... ]
}
```

It's child, the content wrapper has rules to enable vertical scrolling for the content, while the horizontal scrollbar is hidden:

```
.sidebar-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  // content should be scrollable vertically, while horizontal scroll is not allowed
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The box which should overlap the container is positioned absolute:

```
.overlap-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2em;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  z-index: 99;
  // [ ... ]
}
```

Stopping here will let the box overlap the fixed container. However, if the content is scrolled vertically, the box will not be scrolled as well, because it's positioned to the next positioned element, which is `.sidebar-container`. So let's add a `position: relative` to the parent element of the box:

```
.overlap-relative-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Quick and simple, this enables the box to scroll with the content of my fixed container. But it will no more overlaps the fixed container.

The full code can be found in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuebner81/kxpeLn2d/).

### Lessons learned so far

- any relative positioned element within an element that specifies one of the `overflow` CSS rules will clip absolute positioned children
- searching Google and SO will show a lot of results, but I've found no solution for this particular problem. The only reference I found to my issue is in the comments of an blog post called [How to make absolute positioned elements overlap their overflow hidden parent](http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent)
- trying to achieve complex layout scenarios with CSS only seems to harder than I expected

Disclaimer: I know that there is a working solution using onscroll event and JavaScript. And I'm willing to implement this solution to finally solve my issue. Nonetheless, a CSS-only solution would be much nicer IMHO and I want to cut this little Gordian knot :-)

Comment: If those boxes only need to have a fixed width, then I guess you could simulate the effect by making the scroll container wider, and limiting the width of the actual white content area inside - so that the boxes are basically kept inside the element boundaries, and don’t have to get cut off in the first place.

Comment: @04FS Your suggestion works perfect for my needs. You may add it as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the only way to allow child elements to be displayed outside of their parent container in this regard is to use

```
overflow: visible;
```

or, in your case:

```
overflow-x: visible;
```

on the parent container.

Unfortunately, you also want to be able to vertically scroll, which will take precedence over the visibility parameter regardless of the axis it is appended to. Forcing the children to be clipped to the parent dimensions.

Source:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#valdef-overflow-scroll

> "This value indicates that the content is clipped to the padding
>   box, ..."

More information about this conflict/issue:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#scrollable-overflow

If you find a CSS only workaround I'm sure the rest of us would like to know! But it appears you may have to have a non-scrollable sidebar or utilize a different design.

Comment: Even if your answer does not solve the issue, it's a perfect summary of how these CSS properties are working. Thanks a lot. While I'm still thinking about a solution, I suppose I had to add little JavaScript to get things working as desired.

Comment: Well that's kinda the point. I don't think we can give you what you asked for; which is a CSS only solution. :)